# Binding @Published property of parent view's viewModel to @Published property of child view's viewModel: SwiftUI

Tags: swift, mvvm, swiftui

I have this setup:
Parent View: PostsListView
Child View: PostEditView

- PostsListView shows a list short description of posts
- On tap of any post, I present child view: PostEditView
- **Goal is to chage post here call API and when user comes back to PostsListView, it should show updated description**

I'm using MVVM so, in PostsListView

```
@ObservedObject var viewModel : PostsListViewModel    
LazyVGrid(columns: columns) {
                    ForEach(viewModel.posts, id: \.self) { post in
                        NavigationLink(
                            destination: PostEditView(viewModel: PostEditViewModel(post: post))){
                                Text(post: post)
                                    .lineLimit(3)
                        }
                    }
                }
```

I pass view model(PostEditViewModel(post:)) to childView from parent view.

I'm not sure how to bind this 'post' object across both views' viewModels.

FYI viewModels:

PostsListViewModel:

```
class PostsListViewModel: ObservableObject{
    @Published var posts: [Post]
    //api operations....
}
```

PostEditViewModel:

```
class PostEditViewModel: ObservableObject{
    @Published var post: Post
    //custom Post mutation and api operations....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do any special Combine operations. Just make sure that `Post` is a reference type (`class`) and pass the `Post` instance from `PostListViewModel.posts` to `PostEditViewModel.post`, this way whenever you mutate any properties of the `Post` object in the child VM, the same changes will be reflected on the parent VM as well, since the `Post` object is a reference type and both VMs have a reference to the same object.

Comment: TL;DR: 
This introduces another problem of its own, true deep copy. (In some edge cases)

The thing is, I have to do a lot of refactoring if I switch to Class from my current Struct based models. Also, If recall correctly, using reference type models means I have to make sure I create new (copy of) model object if I want perform changes that are temporary or those which should not propagate to all referrers. i.e. Deep Copy.

That's why I'm using Structs value types.

Comment: Have you solved this?